# Unusual behaviour of community

Tags: support, asking-questions

I recently (3 days ago) posted a question. It was quite lengthy and descriptive but I had given it my best to outline the question and made sure it was well written.

Like I mentioned earlier it is 3 days now, and not a single comment/vote/answer which is very unusual of the community. Is this normal or is it just me freaking out? Should I wait for some time?

Edit: I realized after posting this question that, some users might interpret linking this post to my main question had the hidden intent of drawing attention. I am sorry but that was NOT my intent. Since I found it very unusual and no accessible resource pointed out that it was completly normal, I posted this on Meta. That was all I had intended. No strings attached.

Comment: Yes, it is normal. You should wait for some time.

Comment: It could be that the post is so long, people are too daunted to answer or comment on it. Given that many people thinking this wont read the post, it is unlikely they will vote on it either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not unusual.  Math SE receives a huge number of questions every day, and I would imagine that *most* of them receive only a small number of impressions.  This is particularly true of questions which are posted outside of the most active hours (it looks to me like your question was posted very early in the American morning, which makes it less likely to be seen).

Moreover, my impression is that folk often skip over long questions which involve a lot of exposition or computation before getting to the point, particularly when they are of a "check my homework" flavor.  The questions which typically get responses here (for better or worse) are those which can be quickly read and understood, even if the answers are more difficult to write.

In the future, if you feel that a question of yours is not getting enough attention, you might try the following:

1. Edit the question to narrow the focus or to draw attention to a key issue.  I will hasten to add that you should not edit a question *just* to bump it to the top of the queue (editing a question makes it "active", which will promote it to the top of the "active questions" list on the front page)---such edits are considered somewhat abusive.  However, if the question is not getting attention, it is very likely that it is because it needs some edits for clarity or concision.
2. Discuss the question in chat.  The [Mathematics Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) is probably a good place for drawing additional eyeballs to a question.
3. Put a bounty on the question.

In the future, please *do not* post meta questions asking why your main-site question is not getting any attention.  If everyone asked these kinds of questions on meta, the meta site would quickly be overwhelmed with requests for extra attention.

Comment: +1, especially for you last paragraph.  I find it problematic when a user seeks extra attention for their question, for whatever reason (why no answer?  Why the downvotes? why the closure), because meta ought not be a place to seek attention for one's questions.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, if I was misunderstood but my intent was not to draw attention to my question using Meta as a tool. It clearly makes me uncomfortable too and I do not want abuse a wonderful resource as StackExchange. However, I would see it useful if the above points are given a place in the Wiki or some easily accessible resource because clearly it matters and more users are going to feel freaked out if, in future, long posts do not attract attention.

Comment: @PrajvalK This isn't anything new. I posted a longish question a few days ago, put a bounty on it, and still haven't gotten a single response or comment. It happens.